Firestore query with multiple where != conditions
I'm trying to get a single document from a collection in firestore, but its document id has to be different from a list of ids on an array
const excludedIds = ["zyYjPcJG0mqy3WXDQBOZ", "Dics6F0gKPtxKqOuxIhm"];

 const getPotentialMatch = async () => {
    const petsCollection = firestore().collection("pets");
    let query = petsCollection.where("type", "==", "dog");

    excludedIds.forEach((id) => {
      query = query.where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "!=", id);
    });

    query = await query.get();

    let potentialMatches = query.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }));

    console.log(potentialMatches);
  };

The problem is that firestore does not allow me to do more than one where() with '!='. So I need another way for achieving this, but only fetching one document at a time.

Use a not-in query to specify a list of document IDs to exclude, up to the documented limit of 10.
const query = firestore()
    .collection("pets")
    .where("type", "==", "dog")
    .where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "not-in", excludedIds)

This is your only option to make a single query that does what you're saying.

In addition to this way to exclude multiple IDs, the restriction to retrieve only one document can be met by adding a limit clause to the query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data
